# How can obtain a distribution function $f(x,y;s)$ that corresponds to this density plot?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, graphing-functions, uniform-distribution, noise

In the code below (works in SageMathCell) I took a uniformly distributed random variable with support $(0,1)$ and did some operations. Then I generated $10,000$ points randomly sampled from the distribution (see below). I fixed the parameter at $s=.25$ in this plot.

```
def random_point(): 
   return ((exp(.25/ln(random()))), exp(.25/ln(random()))) 
l = [random_point() for k in [1 .. 10000]]
t= point2d(l,size=1.5,color='blue')
P=show(t, aspect_ratio='1')
```

[image]

I'm looking to formally define (obtain an expression) for a bivariate distribution, or surface, (unnormalized) from this plot. So, the more dense the points are in the plot should correspond to a higher point on the surface and less density should correspond to a lower point on the surface.

Furthermore as the parameter $s$ changes, where $s>0,$ the surface should change as well. I can visualize the surface and how it changes with the varying parameter.

> How can I obtain a distribution function, say $f(x,y;s)$ that corresponds to the random points plotted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us define $\phi(x):=\exp\left(\tfrac{s}{\ln(x)}\right), \ \text{with} \ 0<s<1$.

One can establish that this function $[0,1] \to [0,1]$, whatever the value of parameter $s$

- is decreasing.
- is its own inverse,

as illustrated here :

[image]

*Fig. 1 : Function $\phi$ for values of $s$ in [0.05, 1] by steps of 0.05. Case s=0.25 is featured in red.*

The coordinates of the points can be described as :

$$(X,Y)=(\phi(U_1),\ \phi(U_2))$$

where $U_1,U_2 \sim I.U.D([0,1])$, (independent uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$).

The joint CDF of $(X,Y)$ is defined as :

$$F_{X,Y}(x,y)=P(X<x,Y<y)=P(\phi(U_1)<x,\phi(U_2)<y)$$

Due to the fact that $\phi^{-1}=\phi$ and that this function is decreasing :

$$F_{X,Y}(x,y)=P(U_1>\phi(x),U_2>\phi(y))=(1-\phi(x))(1-\phi(y))$$

Its pdf (probability density function) is obtained by taking the mixed second partial derivative :

$$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\frac{\partial^2 F(x,y)}{\partial x \partial y}=\phi'(x)\phi'(y)$$

You will get a graphical representation of surface $z=f(x,y)$ by using the following SAGE code :

```
var('x y s')
s=1/4
f(x,y)=exp(-s/ln(x)-s/ln(y))*s^2/(x*y*(ln(x)^2)*(ln(y)^2));
t=plot3d(f,(x,0,0.75),(y,0,0.75), size=0.3, aspect_ratio=[10,10,0.1])
show(t)
```

with this result :

[image]

*Fig. 2 : The theoretical pdf corresponding to your simulation. Its equation is given in the 3rd line of the program. Please note that we have truncated the domain of definition of $f$ because it isn't bounded in the vicinity of $(1,1)$.*

**Remark:** One should note that function $\phi$ is conjugated to a function $\psi$ which is its own inverse :

$\phi=exp \circ \psi \circ exp^{-1}$ where $\psi(x)=\frac{s}{x}$

Therefore $\phi$ is its own conjugate also.

Answer (score 0):

Area determination for two random real (0,1) by solving the the range intervall of the map

$$ x \to e^{1/(4 \log X)}) $$

$$ \text{Pr}\left[  (e^{\frac{1}{4 \ \log X }} \ \le \ x ,\  e^{\frac{1}{4\ \log Y }} \ \le \ y  )  \right] = \text{Pr}\left[  4 \log X \ \gt  \ \frac{1}{\log x} , \  4 \log Y \ \gt  \ \frac{1}{\log y}  \right]=  \text{Pr}\left[    X \ \gt  \ e^{\frac{1}{4 \log x}} , \   Y \ \gt  \  e^{\frac{1}{4\log y} } \right]  = (1-e^{\frac{1}{4 \log x}})  \ (1-e^{\frac{1}{4 \log y}}))$$

Comment: I don't agree with your first sentence which is for me meaningless. In particular, instead of using the term "area" (strictly speaking, the "area" you consider should be (1-x)(1-y)), you should say you are going to determine the (joint) CDF (Cumulative Distribution Function) and say how to obtain the (joint) Probability Density Function from it. Moreover, it is the (implicit) independence of the two distributions which allow you to multiply probabilities.

Comment: I like more to talk about random variables and their transformation properties than about CDF's and all that blown up trivial stuff from measure theory.

Comment: Maybe my remarks were a little "abrupt", pardon me for that, but the question is about the joint pdf and for a 'newcomer' as the asker hopefuly is , it isn't trivial at all.